# Functional programming convert array of Monads to Single Monad of array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, ramda.js

I have array of monads like this

```
[Left("a"), Left("b"), Left("c")]
```

I want to convert it to this shape

```
Left(["a", "b", "c"])
```

How can I do this?

Is there specific operator for doing something like this or should I write it myself?

Comment: The semantics of your `Either` type is not clear to me. Usually `Left` is interpreted as error with reason and short circuits the traversal. Hence your example would yield the first element of the array `Left("a")`. What behavior should `[Left("a"), Right("b"), Left("c")]` trigger?

Comment: You probably can't avoid writing an `Either` type synonym that behaves the way you want and implements `of`/`ap` from the `Applicative` typeclass. Additionally you'd need a generic `sequenceA` (a better name would be `mapA` I guess) that takes `of`/`ap` from your `Either` type synonym and `map` from `Array` in order to traverse the array in applicative style.

Comment: I have an array of validation rules. each validation return Right if validation pass and return Left if validation fails. I want to convert array of failed validation to one single Left

Comment: The [`Validation` monad-like (but applicative) type](https://github.com/monet/monet.js/blob/master/docs/VALIDATION.md) does what you want and collects errors

Answer (score 3):

As the comments suggested, this would be an unusual function for `Either.Left` type.  Ramda's `sequence` would work with `Either.Right`:

```js
console .log (
  sequence (of, [Right('a'), Right ('b'), Right ('c')] ) //~> Right (['a', 'b', 'c'])
)
```

```html
<script src="//bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<script src="//bundle.run/ramda-fantasy@0.8.0"></script>
<script>const {sequence} = ramda, {Either: {Left, Right, of}} = ramdaFantasy</script>
```

But that's because `Right` connotes successful processing with a resulting value and `Left` connotes a failure which will stop further processing.  It's much like `Maybe` except that it captures the initial error which halted processing.

There are other types that capture multiple errors.  The `Validation` types from [Folktale](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.3.0/en/folktale.validation.html) or [Monet](https://github.com/monet/monet.js/blob/master/docs/VALIDATION.md), for instance, capture multiple errors, but those would generally be wrapped in a single `Failure` instance, not in an array of them.

Clearly you can write your own function for this, but it's unlikely to be one that follows well-defined laws.